# 【Ambari】Build and install Ambari 2.7.5

Tags: ambari

````
```
````

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: Can't get https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/3.x/BUILDS/3.1.4.0-315/tars/hbase/hbase-2.0.2.3.1.4.0-315-bin.tar.gz to /opt/ambari/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-timelineservice/target/embedded/hbase.tar.gz
```

Comment: I also encountered the same problem installing Ambari, how can I solve this?

Comment: Work in progress: https://github.com/apache/ambari/pull/3283

Answer (score 0):

As your question i think you want to install Hortonwork?
He can help you.
https://github.com/steven-matison/dfhz_ddp_mpack.